# PyDev import error even though module is installed

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to use the module [pyelastix](https://github.com/almarklein/pyelastix) in PyDev but the line `import pyelastix` keeps yielding `ImportError: No module named 'pyelastix'`. I'm using a virtual environment called `cv` on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried the following commands to install pyelastix:

```
sudo pip install pyelastix
sudo pip3 install pyelastix
```

inside and outside of the virtual environment. Importing it in the CLI works fine:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyelastix
>>>
```

In Eclipse, the PyDev Interpreter is set to `/home/username/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3.5`. The PYTHONPATH source folder is `/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}`. What could be the issue here?

Comment: I think the problem/solution is the same I gave at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347122/110451 (i.e.: add `pyelastix` to the forced builtins -- see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins for details)

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Thanks. No luck--I added `pyelastix`, `Pyelastix` and `PyElastix` but the same error kept appearing. What seemed to help now was that I searched for the installation location and copied the pyelastix files manually to my virtual environment folder.

Comment: Humm, maybe you didn't select/add the related path where `pyelastix` was when you configured the interpreter?

Comment: I had added the pyelastix folder to System PYTHONPATH before to no avail. However that folder was not located in the virtual environment folder. Could that have been an issue? I also wondered why it wasn't located there in the first place, but that might be worth another question... And I still can't get pyelastix to run -,-

Comment: You have to add the folder above pyelastix to the PYTHONPATH (not the pyelastix folder itself).